# Texdoctk window size for small screens

Tags: texdoc

I use the TeXlive distribution on Debian Bullseye with XFCE. I use a small laptop (~11 inch screen) and I'd like the Settings dialog window of texdoctk to fit my screen and be scrollable, because I cannot access all the options. Here's a screen cap:
[image]

I'm aware this question is probably off-topic in this forum, so if it is I'd like to know where I can ask it.

Thanks in advance!,

Comment: Presumably, you can grab the dialogue and move it around, it's merely the convenience of scaling so that you don't have to? There must be editable XResource(s) to get where you wanna be, but I'm blowed if I can remember such things these days :-( BTW, thanks to your question, I've now discovered <Alt><Left Click> allows you to move the bottom of the active window whilst you're in it i.e. no need to go to the bottom and grab the edge (Y)

Comment: Hello. I can grab the window and move it around; when I place the cursor near its edge, the pointer becomes the resize one, but I cannot change the size; it reverts to moving the window. The Alt+LeftClick trick didn't work with me (XFCE). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was quite simple, really.

One just has to edit the file `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` and modify the line `viewer_pdf = (xdg-open %s) &` to `viewer_pdf = (evince %s) &`.

That's all, folks!